# Cannot compile AudioKit 4.2.2

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I've just downloaded AudioKit most recent version (4.2.2). When I ran the build_frameworks.sh I get the following error:

> [AVAudioUnit?]' has no member 'compactMap'
>           return _effectsChain.compactMap { $0 }
>                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~
>   /Users/sky/Desktop/AudioKit-4.2.2/AudioKit/Common/Nodes/Mixing/Mixer/AKMixer.swift:40:19: error: value of type '[AKNode?]' has no member 'compactMap'
>           self.init(inputs.compactMap { $0 })
>                     ^~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~
>   /Users/sky/Desktop/AudioKit-4.2.2/AudioKit/Common/Internals/AudioKitHelpers.swift:22:16: error: cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type '(Self.Index, offsetBy: Int)'
>           return index(startIndex, offsetBy: offset)
>                  ^
>   /Users/sky/Desktop/AudioKit-4.2.2/AudioKit/Common/Internals/AudioKitHelpers.swift:22:16: note: expected an argument list of type '(Self.Index, offsetBy: Self.IndexDistance)'
>           return index(startIndex, offsetBy: offset)
>                  ^
>   /Users/sky/Desktop/AudioKit-4.2.2/AudioKit/Common/Internals/CoreAudio/AudioUnit+Helpers.swift:101:29: error: missing argument for parameter 'capacity' in call
>               data.deallocate()
>                               ^
>                               capacity: <#Int#>
>   Swift.UnsafeMutablePointer:273:17: note: 'deallocate(capacity:)' declared here
>       public func deallocate(capacity: Int)
>                   ^
>   /Users/sky/Desktop/AudioKit-4.2.2/AudioKit/Common/Nodes/Effects/Reverb/Convolution/AKConvolution.swift:144:41: error: missing argument for parameter 'capacity' in call
>                       theData?.deallocate()
>                                           ^
>                                           capacity: <#Int#>
>   Swift.UnsafeMutablePointer:273:17: note: 'deallocate(capacity:)' declared here
>       public func deallocate(capacity: Int)
>                   ^
>   /Users/sky/Desktop/AudioKit-4.2.2/AudioKit/Common/Nodes/Playback/Phase-Locked Vocoder/AKPhaseLockedVocoder.swift:226:41: error: missing argument for parameter 'capacity' in call
>                       theData?.deallocate()
>                                           ^
>                                           capacity: <#Int#>
>   Swift.UnsafeMutablePointer:273:17: note: 'deallocate(capacity:)' declared here
>       public func deallocate(capacity: Int)
>                   ^
>   /Users/sky/Desktop/AudioKit-4.2.2/AudioKit/Common/Nodes/Effects/AudioKit Operation-Based Effect/AKOperationEffect.swift:28:17: error: value of type '[NSNumber]' has no member 'compactMap'
>                   $0.compactMap { $0.doubleValue }
>                   ^~ ~~~~~~~~~~

I tried to copy the AudioKit source code into the project I was testing: AudioKit's **HelloWorld** project. In this case I have the following error on XCode:

> /Users/sky/Desktop/AudioKit-4.2.2/AudioKit/Common/Internals/AudioUnit Host/AKAudioUnitManager.swift:140:16: Value of type '[AVAudioUnit?]' has no member 'compactMap'

The error is thrown on source code file **AKAudioUnitManager.swift** on the method below:

```
private var linkedEffects: [AVAudioUnit] {
    return _effectsChain.compactMap { $0 }
}
```

Also, playground is not working even with compiled framework.

I use MacOS Sierra, XCode 9.2, Swift 4, iOS 9.2.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.3? `compactMap` only became available in Swift 4.1 and you need Xcode 9.3 for that Swift version.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I'm using XCode 9.2 as mentioned above. Thanks for your answer. I'll update MacOS to High Sierra and XCode to 9.3 and try again.

Comment: The README.MD notes for building the AudioKit frameworks says: "AudioKit requires at least iOS 9.0, macOS 10.11 (El Capitan) or tvOS 9.0"  Yet AudioKit 4.2 appears to require Xcode 9.3 and Swift 4.1.  Xcode 9.3 requires High Sierra 10.13.  That's a whole lot of updating to get this latest AudioKit up.  The release notes really ought to state this.

Comment: I have already upgraded to High Sierra and XCode 9.3, now example projects and playgrounds are compiling.